# Android: SQlite only using one table.

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i am using a SQLite database to do a quiz. i have it fully working using one table but i wanted to create a second table (soon to be third) to have a second quiz with different questions. the problem is that even though i thought i had duplicated the correct methods the class of the second quiz is pulling questions from the first table.

here is the DBHelper

```
public class DBHelper extends  SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triviaQuiz";
// tasks table name
private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
// tasks Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
private static final String TABLE_QUEST2 = "quest";
// tasks Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID2 = "id";
private static final String KEY_QUES2 = "question"; 
private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
private SQLiteDatabase dbase;

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
dbase=db;
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
+ " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
+KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
db.execSQL(sql);
addQuestions();
String sql2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST2 + " ( "
        + KEY_ID2 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES2
        + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
        +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
db.execSQL(sql2);
addQuestions2();
//db.close();
}

private void addQuestions()
{
    Question q1=new Question("8 X 2 " + "=","16", "20", "18", "16");
    this.addQuestion(q1);
    Question q2=new Question("8 X 3  " +    "=", "20", "24", "26", "24");
    this.addQuestion(q2);
    Question q3=new Question("8 X 4 " + " =","30", "35","32","32");
    this.addQuestion(q3);
    Question q4=new Question("8 X 5 " + " = ", "40", "38", "41","40");
    this.addQuestion(q4);
    Question q5=new Question("8 X 6 " +" =","45","48","50","48");
    this.addQuestion(q5);
    Question q6=new Question("8 X 7 " +" =","55","56","58","56");
    this.addQuestion(q6);
    Question q7=new Question("8 X 8 " +" =","64","68","60","64");
    this.addQuestion(q7);
    Question q8=new Question("8 X 9 " +" =","75","72","70","72");
    this.addQuestion(q8);
    Question q9=new Question("8 X 10 " +" =","81","89","80","80");
    this.addQuestion(q9);
    Question q10=new Question("8 X [  ]  " +" = 8","1","9","5","1");
    this.addQuestion(q10);
    Question q11=new Question("8 X [  ] " +" = 24","5","3","6","3");
    this.addQuestion(q11);
    Question q12=new Question("8 X [  ] " +" = 40","6","9","5","5");
    this.addQuestion(q12);
    Question q13=new Question("8 X [  ] " +" = 56","7","8","9","7");
    this.addQuestion(q13);
    Question q14=new Question("8 X [  ] " +" = 80","7","10","9","10");
    this.addQuestion(q14);
}
private void addQuestions2()
{
    Question q1=new Question("2 X 2 " + "=","16", "20", "18", "16");
    this.addQuestion2(q1);
    Question q2=new Question("2 X 3  " +    "=", "20", "24", "26", "24");
    this.addQuestion2(q2);
    Question q3=new Question("2 X 4 " + " =","30", "35","32","32");
    this.addQuestion2(q3);
    Question q4=new Question("2 X 5 " + " = ", "40", "38", "41","40");
    this.addQuestion2(q4);
    Question q5=new Question("2 X 6 " +" =","45","48","50","48");
    this.addQuestion2(q5);
    Question q6=new Question("2 X 7 " +" =","55","56","58","56");
    this.addQuestion2(q6);
    Question q7=new Question("2 X 8 " +" =","64","68","60","64");
    this.addQuestion2(q7);
    Question q8=new Question("2 X 9 " +" =","75","72","70","72");
    this.addQuestion2(q8);
    Question q9=new Question("2 X 10 " +" =","81","89","80","80");
    this.addQuestion2(q9);
    Question q10=new Question("2 X [  ]  " +" = 8","1","9","5","1");
    this.addQuestion2(q10);
    Question q11=new Question("2 X [  ] " +" = 24","5","3","6","3");
    this.addQuestion2(q11);
    Question q12=new Question("2 X [  ] " +" = 40","6","9","5","5");
    this.addQuestion2(q12);
    Question q13=new Question("2 X [  ] " +" = 56","7","8","9","7");
    this.addQuestion2(q13);
    Question q14=new Question("2 X [  ] " +" = 80","7","10","9","10");
    this.addQuestion2(q14);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
// Drop older table if existed
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
// Create tables again
onCreate(db);
}
// Adding new question
public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
//SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
// Inserting Row
dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
}
public void addQuestion2(Question quest) {
    //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_QUES2, quest.getQUESTION());
    values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
    values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
    values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
    values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
    // Inserting Row
    dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST2, null, values);
    }
public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
Question quest = new Question();
quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
quesList.add(quest);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
// return quest list
return quesList;
}
public List<Question> getAllQuestions2() {
List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST2;
dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
Question quest = new Question();
quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
quesList.add(quest);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
// return quest list
return quesList;
}

public int rowcount()
{
int row=0;
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
row=cursor.getCount();
return row;
}
}
```

here is how the questions are set up

```
public class Question 
{
private int ID;
private String QUESTION;
private String OPTA;
private String OPTB;
private String OPTC;
private String ANSWER;
public Question()
{
    ID=0;
    QUESTION="";
    OPTA="";
    OPTB="";
    OPTC="";
    ANSWER="";
}
public Question(String qUESTION, String oPTA, String oPTB, String oPTC,
    String aNSWER)
{

    QUESTION = qUESTION;
    OPTA = oPTA;
    OPTB = oPTB;
    OPTC = oPTC;
    ANSWER = aNSWER;
}
public int getID()
{
    return ID;
}
    public String getQUESTION() {
        return QUESTION;
}
    public String getOPTA() {
        return OPTA;
}
public String getOPTB() {
    return OPTB;
}
public String getOPTC() {
    return OPTC;
}
public String getANSWER() {
    return ANSWER;
}
public void setID(int id)
{
    ID=id;
}
public void setQUESTION(String qUESTION) {
    QUESTION = qUESTION;
}
public void setOPTA(String oPTA) {
    OPTA = oPTA;
}
public void setOPTB(String oPTB) {
    OPTB = oPTB;
}
public void setOPTC(String oPTC) {
    OPTC = oPTC;
}
public void setANSWER(String aNSWER) {
    ANSWER = aNSWER;
}
}
```

here is the class calling the quiz

```
public class Exercise1 extends Activity
{
List<Question> quesList;
int score=0;
int qid=0;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
Button rda, rdb, rdc;
Button butNext;
MediaPlayer mysound;
boolean loaded=false;
private SoundPool soundPool,soundPool2;
int soundID, soundID2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.exercise1);
    DBHelper db=new DBHelper(this);
    quesList=db.getAllQuestions2();
    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
    txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rda=(Button)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    //butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    setQuestionView();
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
           @Override
           public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                   int status) {
               loaded = true;
           }
       });
       soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.correct, 1);
       soundPool2 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

       soundPool2.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
              @Override
              public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                      int status) {
                  loaded = true;
              }
          });

          soundID2 = soundPool2.load(this, R.raw.error, 1);
    rda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String s = currentQ.getANSWER();
            Log.d("Exercise", s);

            if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(rda.getText()))
            {
                score++;
                if(qid<4)
                {
                        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                        setQuestionView();
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Exercise1.this, Exercise2.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                          .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                        .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;

                    soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                    Log.e("Test", "Played sound");

            }
            else 
            {
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                              .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;

                    soundPool2.play(soundID2, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                    Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
                Log.d("Exercise", "not working ");
            }
        }


        });
    rdb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.d("Exercise", "Button B pressed");
            if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(rdb.getText()))
            {
                score++;

                if(qid<4)
                {
                        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                        setQuestionView();
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Exercise1.this, Exercise2.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                          .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                        .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;

                    soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                    Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
            }
            else 
            {
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                              .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;

                    soundPool2.play(soundID2, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                    Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
                Log.d("Exercise", "not working");
            }
        }


        });
    rdc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.d("Exercise", "Button C pressed");
            if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(rdc.getText()))
            {
                score++;
                Log.d("Exercise", "Wrong Answer");

                if(qid<4)
                {
                        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                        setQuestionView();
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Exercise1.this, Exercise2.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                          .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                        .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;

                    soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                    Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
            }
            else
            {
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                              .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;

                    soundPool2.play(soundID2, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                    Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
                Log.d("Exercise", "not workingr");
            }
        }


        });
}
private void setQuestionView()
{
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    qid++;
}

}
```

Comment: It is better idea to not replicate things without strong need. Keep one table `quest` for all questionaries, but probably add one or more extra columns that let you tell those questionaries apart

Answer (score 3):

The table names are the same: `quest`. The create syntax includes `IF NOT EXISTS` so there's no error, either.

Rename the other table to e.g. `quest2`.

Uninstall your app so the old database file is removed.

Comment: ohhh thank you. i just couldn't see that when i was looking through the code

Comment: just commented since i have to wait to accept the answer but yeah that worked perfectly. thanx

Comment: Technically correct, but ideologically wrong answer. Copy/paste or duplicate things over and over again is bad idea

Comment: @mvp then how do you suggest i do it then?

Comment: Yes, from database design point of view the question's approach is probably wrong - but that was not the question.

Comment: Add column like `questionary_id` which should be `1` for first questionary, `2` for second and so on.

Comment: @mvp i might do that later. although quick question if i have the classes in separate packages do i need multiple DBHelpers?

Comment: If by different packages you mean different applications (apk's), then yes - different apk cannot share any common databases in Android (not without setting up content providers). If they are simply different activities in your single apk, then sharing database is perfectly ok.

Comment: yeah its a single APK just different packages within that